# Receiving an error: Programming in Python: Getting "name 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am receiving an error in my frontend code. As I am just currently a learner and not to sure, where why I am receiving this error. TK() is not defined. But I have imported the tkinter library. I refactored my code, to using class, but before I did not have any problems.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from backend import Database


database=Database("dbname='Car_Inventory_db' user='postgres' password='password' host='localhost' port='5432'")

class Window(object):
    
    def __init__(self,window):

        self.window = window
        
        self.window.wm_title("Car Store Inventory")

        l1=Label(window, text="Make")
        l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        l2=Label(window, text="Model")
        l2.grid(row=0,column=2)

        l3=Label(window, text="Year")
        l3.grid(row=3,column=0)

        l4=Label(window, text="First Owner")
        l4.grid(row=1,column=0)

        l5=Label(window, text="VIN#")
        l5.grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.make_text=StringVar()
        self.e1=Entry(window,textvariable=self.make_text)
        self.e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.model_text=StringVar()
        self.e2=Entry(window,textvariable=self.model_text)
        self.e2.grid(row=0,column=3)


        self.year_text=StringVar()
        self.e3=Entry(window,textvariable=self.year_text)
        self.e3.grid(row=3,column=1)


        self.firstOwner_text=StringVar()
        self.e4=Entry(window,textvariable=self.firstOwner_text)
        self.e4.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.vin_text=StringVar()
        self.e5=Entry(window,textvariable=self.vin_text)
        self.e5.grid(row=1,column=3)


        self.list1=Listbox(window, height=6,width=35)
        self.list1.grid(row=4,column=0,rowspan=6,columnspan=2)

        sb1=Scrollbar(window)
        sb1.grid(row=4,column=2, rowspan=6)

        self.list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
        sb1.configure(orient='vertical', command=self.list1.yview)

        self.list1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.get_selected_row)

        b1=Button(window, text="View all", width=12,command=self.view_command)
        b1.grid(row=2, column=3)

        b2=Button(window, text="Search Entry", width=12,command=self.search_command)
        b2.grid(row=3, column=3)

        b3=Button(window, text="Add Entry", width=12, command=self.add_command)
        b3.grid(row=3, column=4)

        b4=Button(window, text="Update Selected", width=12, command=self.update_command)
        b4.grid(row=4, column=3)

        b5=Button(window, text="Delete Selected", width=12,command=self.delete_command)
        b5.grid(row=5, column=3)


        b5=Button(window, text="Close", width=12, command=window.destroy)
        b5.grid(row=6, column=3)
        
    def get_selected_row(self,event):
        
        try:
            global selected_tuple
            index=self.list1.curselection()[0]
            selected_tuple=self.list1.get(index)
            self.e1.delete(0,END)
            self.e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
            self.e2.delete(0,END)
            self.e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
            self.e3.delete(0,END)
            self.e3.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])
            self.e4.delete(0,END)
            self.e4.insert(END,selected_tuple[4])
            self.e5.delete(0,END)
            self.e5.insert(END,selected_tuple[5])
        except IndexError:
            pass
            
    
        

    # this will view all the items in currently in the database 
    def view_command(self):
        self.list1.delete(0,END)
        for row in database.view():
            self.list1.insert(END,row)

    # this command will search the items in currently in the database(backend)
    def search_command(self):
        self.list1.delete(0,END)
        for row in database.search(self.make_text.get(),self.model_text.get(),self.year_text.get(),self.firstOwner_text.get(),self.vin_text.get()):
            self.list1.insert(END,row)

    # this command add new items in the database(backend)
    def add_command(self):
        database.insert(self.make_text.get(),self.model_text.get(),self.year_text.get(),self.firstOwner_text.get(),self.vin_text.get())
        self.list1.delete(0,END)
        self.list1.insert(END,(self.make_text.get(),self.model_text.get(),self.year_text.get(),self.firstOwner_text.get(),self.vin_text.get()))


    def delete_command(self):
        database.delete(self.selected_tuple[0])


    def update_command(self):
        database.update(selected_tuple[0],self.make_text.get(),self.model_text.get(),self.year_text.get(),self.firstOwner_text.get(),self.vin_text.get())
    
window=TK()
Window(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Error:
window=TK()
NameError: name 'TK' is not defined

Comment: It's `Tk`, not `TK`.

Comment: also don't use `*` when importing

Comment: The reason to now use * is that all functions in the library are brought in at a the same call level as your actual code.  So if there is a function that has the same signature like print() in the library it conflicts with the python version of print(), so you should do import tkinter as tk so when you call the tkinter print funciton, it's tk.print()  [note I don't think there is a print funtion in tkinter, just using it as an example]